# Cross Referencer for github repositories

Tags: github, cross-reference

I have used the free-electrons elixir cross referencer to browse through the linux source code and be able to jump to the definition and implementation of the defined functions, etc.

I was wondering if there is a similar cross referencer for github repositories

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a website that does this, though I am not sure if they index the implementations and declarations like elixir does for linux kernel . **Sourcegraph** can help  you with this.

For example if you wanted to view the linux kernel you would type

> https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/torvalds/linux

Answer (score 0):

Since June 11th, 2019 (2 years later), you don't need Sourcegraph.

See "[Jump to definition in public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-06-11-jump-to-definition-in-public-repositories/)"

> Jump to definition is now available for a **subset of public repositories**—supported in Go, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, and TypeScript.
>
> Hovering over function and method calls will expose jump-to-definition links for all call sites in the blob content, within the same repository.
> We use the **[recently open-sourced `semantic` library](https://github.com/github/semantic)** to find definitions and call sites in your code.

See more at "[Navigating code on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/navigating-code-on-github)":

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/jump-to-definition-link.png]

> Tip: Jump to definition works for *active* branches.
> If the feature is enabled for you but you don't see links to the definitions of functions and methods, push to the branch and try again.

See it in action for instance in [`moby/moby` `cmd/dockerd/daemon.go`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go#L77-L92).

---

Starting August 2019, you can "[Find all references in public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-08-16-find-all-references-in-public-repositories/)"

> Find all references is now available for a subset of public repositories—supported in Go, JavaScript, PHP, Python, Ruby, and TypeScript.
> Hovering over function and method names in the code view will expose links to all of the calls to that function or method within the same repository.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/find-all-references-tab.png]

> We use the recently open sourced semantic library to find definitions and call sites in your code: [**`github/semantic`**](https://github.com/github/semantic)
>
> **`semantic`** is a Haskell library and command line tool for parsing, analyzing, and comparing source code.